# Fast way to generate the coordinates along the perimeter of a quadrilateral given its vertices?

Tags: python, image-processing, linear-algebra

I'm working on writing a document scanner, and I've come across a problem. Here's the general pipeline of my app:
- Detect edges in the image
- Find straight lines in the edge image
- Find all quadrilaterals of a certain area formed by the intersections of those lines
- Determine which quad is the document by looking at the ratio of edge pixels vs total pixels on the perimeter of each quad and using the max

However, that last step is extremely slow for large images because I generate and test all coordinates in the image. Is there a faster way to generate the x,y coordinates of an image that lay on the perimeter of a particular quadrilateral?

The project is in Python, if that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe I forgot about [Bresenham's Line Algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). Problem solved